# how can i replicate this background texture and color style in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

This is my example code of my app. I want my background to be like this image with soft pink transition to soft blue with some texture soft blur on top of it.
[image]

how may i replicate this with just swiftui?

Comment: This appears to be three total layers, with varying degrees of opacity. Two radial, and one linear gradient. Give me just a few to see if I can come up with something on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first thing you're going to want to do is to utilize `LinearGradient` and `RadialGradient` which are the two types of gradients that you can use to compose several layers. There are other ways you can do it by using `.background` or `.overlay` modifiers however in my example I want to keep it as simple as possible and allow you the freedom to explore other options with it. I've created two extensions so that you can simply reference `LinearGradient.blueClearGradient`, for example, directly anywhere in your app. NOTE:: I used different colors, feel free to use what you want to use for your colors. I did this to make it more visually apparent what the individual pieces of the view were composed of.

```
extension LinearGradient {  
    static let blueClearGradient = LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .clear],
                                             startPoint: .bottom,
                                             endPoint: .top)
}

extension RadialGradient {
    static let radialYellowGradient = RadialGradient(colors: [.yellow, .clear],
                                                 center: .topLeading,
                                                 startRadius: 100,
                                                 endRadius: 400)

    static let radialRedGradient = RadialGradient(colors: [.red, .clear],
                                               center: .topTrailing,
                                               startRadius: 100,
                                               endRadius: 400)
}
```

Once you have those extensions it's as simple as utilizing them the same as you would any other view. You can use them to `.fill` or even as a straight up view themselves. In this example, I used them as a `.fill` for a shape.

```
struct GradientExample: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(RadialGradient.radialRedGradient)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(RadialGradient.radialYellowGradient)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(LinearGradient.blueClearGradient)
        }
    }
}
```

Doing it this way produces a view that might look something like this.

[image: Gradient Example]

Comment: it was looking nice after all but do you know if possible i can manage to add a blurry texture on top?

Comment: @Eudora yes you can simply add `.blur()` to either the parent view, eg `ZStack{}`or to each individual portion to compose it the way you want; However `.blur()` is an intensive process and it won't make too much of a difference to gradients. You're better off modifying the `startRadius` and `endRadius` properties of each to get the desired appearance, because it'll do the same thing as the blur, just at a lower CPU cost.